# Error in creating qcreport with minfi package

Tags: r

I am working with Illumina 450K DNA methylation data using the minfi package in R.

Following the [minfi tutorial](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/minfi/inst/doc/minfi.pdf), I get the following error when entering the `qcreport` command:

```
qcReport(RGset, sampNames = pd$Sample_Name,sampGroups = pd$Sample_Group, pdf = "qcReport.pdf")

Error *"missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"* in:
if (!isVersioned(x) || !isCurrent(x)["eSet"]) x <- updateObject(x) :   missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

What could be the problem?